# Do Streaming and Tree-Based XML parsers consume similar amounts of memory at the beginning in JAVA

Tags: java, xml, dom, xml-parsing, sax

There are two main parsers to read an XML.

1. Streaming parser - (eg : SAX, StAX)
2. Tree-Based parser - (eg : DOM, AXIOM etc)

It is said the Streaming Parsers uses less memory than the tree based parsers. One thing to be noted is unlike tree-based parsers, Streaming parsers doesn't provide the entire XML tree to be navigated by the developer. In there, we can navigate based on the event. And after each event is handled, the data (xml content) that associated with that event can be discarded from the memory by the processor.

But, in both cases we must provide the entire XML content to the parsers. So, internally that parser must store that entire XML content in memory to navigate through each node. So, my argument is how is Streaming parsers consumes less memory than tree-based parsers?

1. When it is started to read a XML, is both Streaming and Tree-Based parsers consumes similar amount of memory?
2. What are the techniques that Streaming parsers use to consumes less memory than tree-based parsers?

SAX :

```
SAXParserFactory        factory     =   SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
SAXParser               saxPaser    =   factory.newSAXParser();

ResultHandler           handler     =   new ResultHandler();

InputSource             input       =   new InputSource(new StringReader(xml));             
input.setEncoding("utf-8");
saxPaser.parse(input,handler);
```

StAX:

```
    XMLInputFactory             inputFactory    = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
    XMLEventReader              eventReader     = inputFactory.createXMLEventReader(new FileInputStream(configFile));
```

AXIOM :

```
    XMLStreamReader             parser                              = XMLInputFactory.newInstance().createXMLStreamReader(new StringBufferInputStream(responseXML));
    OMElement                   documentElement                     = new StAXOMBuilder(parser).getDocumentElement();
```

References :

- http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaXML/article.html
- http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/01/xml-parsing-using-saxparser-with.html
- http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-xml/index.html
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uaclko4rbZQ
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BVhKoEQmpcA
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kvb9B_7W8rs

Comment: "In both cases we must provide the entire XML content to the parsers." This is the wrong assumption. You usually provide an input stream for reading the XML to a SAX or StAX parser. And these parsers do not load the entire XML into memory. They _stream_ it.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose : But each time we are giving the entire XML string to each of those parsers. Right? So, that string must be in memory to read within the parser.

Comment: Hmmm ... I do not exactly know what you mean with "giving the entire XML string to each of those parsers". All three tutorials you mentioned are working on _files_ not on _strings_ (I did not look at the youtube clips). But, yes, if you have already an XML string in memory, then it will consume its whole size in memory. But this is already true _without_ parsing.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are confusing two parts:

1. How you the developer provide the XML to the parser
2. How the parser reads the data

For the first part you have two choices (actually more than two but we'll consider the two most common).

1. You can tell the parser to read from a file or socket.  In that case the streaming parser never has a complete copy of the XML in memory. However, if you are loading the XML into memory as a String and then feeding that to the parser, it is YOU who have consumed the memory, not the parser.  It will dutifully "stream" over your string and not keep its own internal copy of the XML.
2. In the case of the DOM parser, it does build a complete in-memory tree. In the case where you fed it a file, the actual file contents are discarded after building the DOM structure.  When you provide a String, at the end of parsing you have the newly built DOM tree PLUS the String containing the XML source.

If you don't need to navigate the tree in random directions, use a stream parser.  Otherwise you will have to use a DOM.

Comment: +1. " In that case the streaming parser never has a complete copy of the XML in memory. However, if you are loading the XML into memory as a String and then feeding that to the parser, it is YOU who have consumed the memory, not the parser. It will dutifully "stream" over your string and not keep its own internal copy of the XML" Well said Jim. Thanx. Yes. I also feel that I missed something. Thank you again,

Answer (score 1):

It's rather a shame that it has become so common to speak of tree-building libraries such as DOM or JDOM as "parsers". Really there are two bit of software here: a parser (which reads the sequence of characters in the source, analyses it, and emits a sequence of events representing syntactic units such as start and end tags), and a tree builder, which takes the sequence of events from a parser and builds an in-memory tree.

Your choice is therefore not between two different kinds of parser. Your choice is whether to have the parser pass events straight to your application, or to have it pass events to a tree-builder, and then pass the completed tree to your application.

The parser does not use a significant amount of memory. The tree-builder does. But the tree-builder presents the information to the application in a form that is much easier to process.